# How to align vertically an image in relation to another element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following visual effect:

[image: Visual Effect]

I've tried various things but was unable to do it. Here's the most simplified version of it on codepen:

[image: Picture from codepen]

The link to it is [codepen](http://codepen.io/vbelenky/pen/ZYQErq?editors=110). The HTML is:

```
<div class="outerContainer">
  <button>LOREM IPSUM</button>

  <!-- This is the question mark image -->
  <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/adoqiv.png">
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
// Just to see the border for testing
$test-border-width: 3px;
$test-border-style: dotted;

.outerContainer {
  border: $test-border-width $test-border-style green;

  // Don't span entire width because later will center container
  display: inline-block;

  button {
    border: $test-border-width $test-border-style red;

    // I would like to be able to change the font size 
    // without having to worry about the question mark image,
    // that is, for the image to be automatically vertically aligned
    // in the middle.
    font-size: 4em;
  }

  img {
    border: $test-border-width $test-border-style cyan;
  }  

}
```

Advice greatly appreciated. Also, if possible, the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set both children to `vertical-align: middle`:

```css
.outerContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px dotted green;
}
button {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 3px dotted red;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 3px dotted cyan;
}
/* for testing different font sizes */
.outerContainer:nth-child(1) button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.outerContainer:nth-child(2) button {
  font-size: 4em;
}
.outerContainer:nth-child(3) button {
  font-size: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
  <button>LOREM IPSUM</button>
  <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/adoqiv.png">
</div>

<div class="outerContainer">
  <button>LOREM IPSUM</button>
  <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/adoqiv.png">
</div>
<div class="outerContainer">
  <button>LOREM IPSUM</button>
  <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/adoqiv.png">
</div>
```

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxrvPe)

Comment: Works great. Would you be able to explain why it works?

Comment: It merely uses [vertical-align](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) property. I have added it to both elements so that vertical alignment is relative to the taller element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `vertical-align: middle;` on img tag but it has to share the same height as text in button (which is not that bad since you can set the height in ems as well):

```
 .spaSwitch {

  button {
    display: inline-block;
    $button-color: #a84040;
    background-color: $button-color;
    border-color: $button-color;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    height: 2.1em;
    padding: 0 0.4em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .questionMarkHolder {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 2.1em;
    height: 2.1em;

    img {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
 }
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNrwVr

Also, using pseudoelement might suit you better as you won't have to set heights of any elements:

```
.spaSwitch {
  $padding: 0.4em;

  button {
    position: relative;
    $button-color: #a84040;
    background-color: $button-color;
    border-color: $button-color;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: $padding;
    cursor: pointer;

      &:after {
        content: url('http://i60.tinypic.com/adoqiv.png');
        position: absolute;
        right: -30px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -12px; // half of the height
        cursor: default;
      }
    }
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyeLbj

Comment: Otherwise if you don't want to set the height of your elements, you can read [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)